# Print to screen from a Process using Pool

Tags: python, printing, pool, multiprocess

I've been trying to print to screen stuff from the process spawned by Pool. Unfortunately nothing comes up! I need this, as I'll have 4 processes running at the same time for quite a long, and I need to get some estimated and print some information meanwhile.

I've been browsing around trying to figured out by myself, but I haven't understand if this is really possible or how to do it. Using Process rather than Pool? Any help & code will be really appreciated!

Here is a very simple example I'll be happy to make it work!

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def printer(i):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print "#%i PID: %i" % (i,pid)
    return pid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    res = pool.map(printer,[1,2])
    pool.terminate()
    print "PIDs", res
```

I would like this to print what "printer" does before terminate the pool and print "res".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pool.imap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap) to iterate over results as they get ready.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def printer(i):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print "#%i PID: %i" % (i,pid)
    return pid

def print_result(res):
    print "PID", res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    res = pool.imap(printer,range(10), 1)
    for pid in res:
        print pid
    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, what I need to print is what "printer" will print normally. If you run printer(1) you'll get something like "#1 PID: 4300". This is what I need!